# Firebird 2.5 SQL query execution plan not using index with OR statement

Tags: sql, query-optimization, parent-child, firebird2.5, sql-execution-plan

First: I'm not a DB expert, so please indulge if the question is trivial...

I have a query on a child table `CHILD` looking up some values in the master table `PARENT` to determine whether or not the entry is to be loaded.

The query looks like this

```
SELECT C.*, P.DATE, P.STATUS 
FROM CHILD C, PARENT P
WHERE C.PARENT_ID = P.ID 
AND (P.DATE > '01.01.2015' OR (P.STATUS <> 1 AND P.STATUS <> 9));
```

I've chosen `STATUS` values on purpose to highlight that I need to use inequalities as status values I need to select from are non-contiguous.

I have a foreign key on `PARENT.ID` for field `CHILD.PARENT_ID`, and created an index on `CHILD.PARENT_ID`. I've also created an index on table `PARENT` on fields `DATE` and `STATUS`.

Now, when I replace the `OR` with and `AND` `CHILD` uses the index on `PARENT_ID` and `PARENT` uses the index on `DATE, STATUS` which was what I expect.

But when using `OR`, the query uses the natural plan on `CHILD` and the primary key index on `PARENT.ID`.

Same occurs if I apply the query to the parent table only:

```
SELECT P.* FROM PARENT P WHERE (P.DATE > '01.01.2015' OR (P.STATUS <> 1 AND P.STATUS <> 9));
```

Is there a way to optimize such a query to use better than natural plans??

Comment: Can you please update two plans here:Lhttps://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/..Also table count,indexes on both the tables

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Please [edit] your question add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2):

If you write the 'or', every P.DATE might be a hit. Also every P.STATUS might be a hit. That aren't very good prerequisites if you want to use an index.

Here you'll have to help your system and ask 2 separate questions and concatenate them with a UNION. Like

```
SELECT C.*, P.DATE, P.STATUS 
  FROM CHILD C, PARENT P 
 WHERE C.PARENT_ID = P.ID 
   AND P.DATE > '01.01.2015' 
UNION
SELECT C.*, P.DATE, P.STATUS 
  FROM CHILD C, PARENT P 
 WHERE C.PARENT_ID = P.ID 
   AND P.STATUS <> 1 
   AND P.STATUS <> 9;
```

Note: if most values of P.STATUS are unequal 1 and unequal 9 you'll still have a bad performance. Just imagine you're looking in a book, with all words indexed, for the word 'and'. It will be at every page; reading the book sequentially would be faster than using an index.

Answer (score 2):

This can be quite hard for an optimizer to use indexes on.  First, rewrite the query using `join`s:

```
SELECT C.*, P.DATE, P.STATUS 
FROM CHILD C JOIN
     PARENT P
     ON C.PARENT_ID = P.ID 
WHERE P.DATE > '2015-01-01' OR P.STATUS NOT IN (1, 9);
```

You can rewrite this using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT C.*, P.DATE, P.STATUS 
FROM CHILD C JOIN
     PARENT P
     ON C.PARENT_ID = P.ID 
WHERE P.DATE > '2015-01-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT C.*, P.DATE, P.STATUS 
FROM CHILD C JOIN
     PARENT P
     ON C.PARENT_ID = P.ID 
WHERE P.DATE <= '2015-01-01' AND   -- This condition prevents overlaps
      P.STATUS NOT IN (1, 9);
```

The subqueries can now make use of indexes on `PARENT(DATE, ID)` and `PARENT(STATUS, DATE, ID)`.

However, it is not clear that filtering the results will actually make the query faster.  It depends on how selective the filters are.